# Obtaining the net force for a block on a ramp to slide up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm trying to solve a problem but I'm getting a different answer. The question is

A horizontal force $F$ is exerted on a 20kg box to slide it up a $30°$ incline. The friction force retarding the motion is 80 $N$. How large must $F$ be if the acceleration of the moving box is to be (a) zero and (b) 0.75 $\frac{m}{s^2}$?

I tried to solve the (a) first and the formula that I used was $F-F\sin\theta-F_f=ma$ but since on the (a) the desired acceleration is zero it will become $F-F\sin\theta-F_f=0$. My answer is 178 $N$ which far from 0.21 $kN$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adjust the forces such that the normal force is vertical and the frictional force is horizontal, then the sum of the forces relative to the plane of the slope is:
$$Fcos\theta - mgsin\theta - F_f = ma_{sum}$$
Sometimes it's helpful to rotate frames of reference in cases like this where we can avoid calculating the normal force and the frame doesn't affect the magnitude of the forces.